# Is there a way to forward old logs to Splunk with a new index?

Tags: splunk

I have logs that were already forwarded to an index (A). I have zipped up the logs and saved them. I noticed that index A had a very low retention period, so I was losing logs in Splunk before I could do my analysis. I created a new index (B) with a longer retention period and want to forward the old zipped logs to this new index. I changed the config and restarted splunk forwarder. I don't see the unzipped logs being forwarded to the new index. Am I missing something? Is there an easy way to do this? I don't mind copying my log data to a new file. I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't need to create a new index.

First you need to [Change a retirement and archiving policy](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/Indexer/Setaretirementandarchivingpolicy)

Then you can [Restore archived indexed data](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/Indexer/Restorearchiveddata).
In this step, you can ask splunk to reindex the "Thaw" logs and keep it for as long as you want.